# How do I find out the numeric ID of the current Postgres Transaction?

Tags: postgresql

On psql I can type the following:

```
BEGIN;
```

what do I type to get the current id of the newly created transaction?

I am trying to put together a demo that explains how vaccum and MVVC work in postgres. For example `select xmin, xmax, * from test;` shows the xmin and xmax of each row from the point of view of the current transaction.

I understand the basic theory of it but want to put together an interactive exercise such that I can have two psql consoles open and then have a set of step by step instructions that show mvcc and vaccum work.

**How do I get the current postgres transaction id?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the transaction id from:

```
txid_current()
```

You can additionally get the in-progress transactions in the snaption it's seeing from:

```
txid_snapshot_xip(txid_current_snapshot())
```

A few more functions are detailed in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Note that calling `txid_current()` will assign a transaction ID if the session didn't already have one. Read-only sessions only have a virtual transaction ID.

Comment: Use pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned() From Docs: "It's best to use this variant if the transaction might otherwise be read-only, to avoid unnecessary consumption of an XID."

Answer (score 5):

Postgres has added `txid_current_if_assigned()` in [version 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT).

Comment: `pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()` in version 13+ (txid_current_if_assigned still exists but is deprecated)

Answer (score 3):

["System Information Functions", "Transaction IDs and Snapshots"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT).